# Java - Convert all words in a string but one to camelcase

Tags: java, string, camelcasing

I would like to convert a string to camelcase but avoid a word in that string.

```
public class camelTest
{
public static void main(String []args)
{
    String test = "St. KiTTs aND Nevis";
    System.out.println(toCamelCase(test));
}


    public static String toCamelCase(String test1)
    {
        String[] split = test1.split(" ");

        String ret = "";
        for (int i=0;i<split.length;i++)
        {
            ret=ret+split[i].substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+split[i].substring(1).toLowerCase()+" ";

        }
    return ret.trim();}
   }
```

The code above has the output of:
St. Kitts And Nevis

I would like it instead to say:
St. Kitts and Nevis

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i=0;i<split.length;i++){
    if(split[i].equalsIgnoreCase("and")){
        ret = ret + split[i].toLowerCase() + " ";
    } else {
        ret=ret+split[i].substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+split[i].substring(1).toLowerCase()+" ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String toCamelCase(String test1)
{
    String[] split = test1.split(" ");

    String ret = "";
    for (int i=0;i<split.length;i++)
    {
        if (split[i].equalsIgnoreCase("and")) {
            ret=ret+split[i].toLowerCase()+" ";
            continue;
        }
        ret=ret+split[i].substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+split[i].substring(1).toLowerCase()+" ";

    }
return ret.trim();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are previously know the word that does not need to start with capital letter, then you can check for these word before start capitalizing the first letter.

```
String someString = "and";
if(split[i].equalsignorecase(someString))
```

where `somString` could be any string that you do not want to capitalize its first letter.